# How to pass object array as props to a custom component in react native?

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, object, react-props

I have fetched some data from an API as a JSON array in componentDidMount method as below.

```
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('http://..someAPI../product/')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(resJson => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: resJson,
        });
        var objects = this.state.dataSource;
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
          console.log('Item Name: ' + objects[i].productName);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

In here I get console.log output as I want. Now I want to pass the array in a loop as a prop to a custom component, but it gives error.
My render method looks like this

```
return (
      <View>
        <Content>
          {this.state.dataSource.map(item => {
            <Product Name={item.productName} price={item.price}/>;
          })}
        </Content>
      </View>
    );
```

My original Json object looks like this

```
[
   {
        "category": [
            "Food",
            "Bread",
            "Bun"
        ],
        "_id": "1",
        "productName": "Sausage bun",
        "price": 70,
        "details": "test product",
    },
    {
        "category": [
            "Food",
            "Bread",
            "Bun"
        ],
        "_id": "2",
        "productName": "Fish Pastry",
        "price": 50,
        "details": "test product",
    }
]
```

I want to pass these data to display the products as a loop. How can I do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Whats the error that you get? and do you set a value for dataSource when you initialize? something like an empty array perhaps

Comment: I have initialized dataSource as null in the state. And I get  "null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dataSource.map') " as the error message

Comment: instead of null use an empty array that will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Since data loading is asynchronous you probably have uninitialised state.

As a safer coding practice you could something like

```
{this.state.dataSource && this.state.dataSource.map(item => {
            return <Product Name={item.productName} price={item.price}/>;
          })}
```

Depending on your webpack configuration , you can also use optional chaining https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
{this.state?.dataSource?.map(item => {
            <Product Name={item.productName} price={item.price}/>;
          })}
```

Also,
initialize your state

```
this.state = {
   dataSource: []
}
```

Comment: I tried both of the methods after initializing the state as you said. Then that error goes away but data does not pass to the component and I get a warning message saying " Functions are not valid as a React child, This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render, Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it "

Comment: ok @SulaRanawake. The second error is because you dont have return here. ```{this.state.dataSource.map(item => {
            return <Product Name={item.productName} price={item.price}/>;
          })}```

Comment: Thank you soo much, this solved it! as I am new to react native I miss such things sometimes.